# Creating a validator that relies on a foreign key's field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to perform validation in serializers.py with a test that involves a foreign field.

*Context: A user can create a `Host` and assign it to a `Network`. Networks have a network address - **net** (e.g. 10.23.0.0) and a subnet mask - **netmask** (e.g. 16). Hosts can have any IP address, so long as they belong to the right CIDR block for the given Network the host is in.*

When creating a Host, an `ipv4_addr` must be supplied. I want to check if it falls within the right network but am not sure how to reference the Network foreign key.

The validator:

```
def validate_ipv4_addr(self, value):
    """
    Check that IP address given falls within the right network
    """
    net = Network.ipv4_net
    netmask = Network.ipv4_netmask
    cidr = net + "/" + netmask
    if ipaddress.IPv4Address(value) not in ipaddress.IPv4Network(cidr):
        raise serializers.ValidationError(value + " is not a valid IP address for " + cidr)
    return value
```

I have class method which allows me to get the **net** and **netmask** in the first place (below) - but I have little idea how to call it from the validator as I am unsure what to pass for `obj` to it.

```
def get_ipv4_netmask(self, obj):
    return obj.network.ipv4_netmask
```

`Network` from models.py:

```
class Network(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    ipv4_net = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', null=True)
    ipv4_gateway = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', null=True)
    ipv4_netmask = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(32)])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Network"
        verbose_name_plural = "Networks"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`Host` from models.py:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ipv4_addr = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Host"
        verbose_name_plural = "Hosts"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Without seeing your model how someone could possibly identify the FK field?

Comment: I've made an edit and the relevant parts from models.py are now included